# Displaying a Default Value in a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ComboBox whose XAML looks as follows:

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Row = "0" Style="{DynamicResource chartStackPanel}">
        <Label    Content="Port:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        <ComboBox Width="75" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,0,0,0" SelectedValue="{Binding Port, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C43"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C46" IsSelected="True"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C47"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C48"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

The style referenced above is defined as follows:

When the ComboBox is first displayed, I'd like the 'C46' item displayed in the ComboBox. However, when this loads, the ComboBox is blank. What's interesting is that the source property, in my VM, is getting set to 'C46'. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`? (see also `SelectedValuePath`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you have a source collection in your ViewModel. Therefore, why do you specify ComboBoxItems one by one in XAML? I think you should have in your ViewModel a Collection of Items property and also SelectedItem property. In the constructor you can set the SelectedItem. It can looks as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Items { get;set; }

public MyClass SelectedItem
{
  get {return this.selectedItem;}
  set {
       this.selectedItem = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
      }
}
```

And in your constructor after Items property is initialized:

```
this.SelectedItem = Items[x]
```

Your XAML can looks as follows then:

```
<ComboBox Width="75" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,0,0,0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow the same and it show 'C46' when screen loads. 
However, the VM will show `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: C46` instead of `C46` since you didn't use ***SelectedValuePath*** to specific the binding value path

I use `SelectedValuePath="Content"` it would show 'C46'

Comment: How any changes are reflected in the VM isn't the problem here. When the user changes the Port, the change is reflected in the VM and I can deal with it appropriately. I just can't figure out why nothing displays when my form first loads.

Answer (score -2):

// View

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCategories" Width="300" Height="24" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" />
```

// ViewModel

```
private CategoryModel _SelectedCategory;
        public CategoryModel SelectedCategory
        {
            get { return _SelectedCategory; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedCategory = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> _Categories;
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Categories
        {
            get { return _Categories; }
            set
            {
                _Categories = value;
                _Categories.Insert(0, new CategoryModel()
                {
                    CategoryId = 0,
                    CategoryName = " -- Select Category -- "
                });
                SelectedCategory = _Categories[0];
                OnPropertyChanged("Categories");

            }
        }
```